# How to avoid HTTP Header Injection (new lines characters)

Tags: php, security, http-headers, code-injection

I sometimes use user data in php function `header` like this :

```
header('Location : test' . $user_data);
```

I used to remove `\n` and `\r` to prevent header injection but is there any other new lines characters ? I wrote `Location` in my example, but it can be something else, I know I have to validate and sanitize URL, my question is about new lines in header.

Comment: By the way, `Location: ` header must be an absolute URL (i.e. it must start from `http://` or whatever protocol you're going to use)

Comment: Relative `Location:` headers, although against RFC, work as expected with virtually all browsers.

Comment: I don't understand : `header('Location: test.php');` seems to work (I've just tried), I can use relative URL (PHP/Apache)

Comment: @raina77ow : thanks ! I didn't noticed that. PHP send a warning (I've just tried), and no redirection has been made.

Comment: rap-2-h, just because relative paths work with your browser doesn't mean they will work everywhere (web browsers aren't the only applications that browse the web [e.g. search engine bots]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-changelog):

> (since 4.4.2 and 5.1.2) This function now prevents more than one
>   header to be sent at once as a protection against header injection
>   attacks.

So I suppose even that CRLF replacement you've already did is not necessary.

Comment: (Assuming >4.4.2 or >5.1.2 is being used.)

Comment: Yes, but then you go on to say "So I suppose even that CRLF replacement you've already did is not necessary." which is making that assumption, so if someone skips the quote, they'll assume they don't have to do it either (people don't read haha).

Comment: thanks ! I didn't noticed that. PHP send a warning (I've just tried), and no redirection has been made (but my question is still valid, because my application is PHP 5.1.X compatible, so I can't accept your response right now (maybe later, I voted +1 for now))

Comment: I know it's old, but I just found out today (6 jan 2017), using PHP 5.2.17, that PHP allows multi line header using CR only (\r, ASCII 13, %0D), which unfortunately it is treated by Chrome browser as a new line, allowing header injection. I hope it is useful to someone checking out this page.